# Scalar SQL function not returning correct JSON values

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I need JSON returned from a SQL Server scalar function.

I wrote this query inside SSMS

```
SELECT 
    Id AS [Expense.Id],
    Amount AS [Expense.Amount],
    StudentName AS [Expense.StudentName]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Expenses] 
FOR JSON PATH, Root('Expenses')
```

Here is result (EXACTLY WHAT I WANTED)

```
"Expenses": [
    {
      "Expense": {
        "Id": "43838475-5BBC-4C2A-A1E9-85F9E55298D3",
        "Amount": 0.0000000e+000,
        "StudentName": "Carter"
      }
    },
    {
      "Expense": {
        "Id": "38AC0403-5DCF-42E1-A103-5D33DB905F57",
        "Amount": 0.0000000e+000,
        "StudentName": "Louis"
      }
    },
    {
      "Expense": {
        "Id": "5E6EB81E-C988-4D7C-98AB-FA814CFF875A",
        "Amount": 0.0000000e+000,
        "StudentName": "David"
      }
    }
```

Now then all I have to do is wrap it in a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[get_all_json] 
    (@input nvarchar)
RETURNS nvarchar
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return nvarchar

    SET @return = (SELECT 
                       Id AS [Expense.Id],
                       Amount AS [Expense.Amount],
                       StudentName AS [Expense.StudentName]
                   FROM 
                       [dbo].[Expenses] 
                   FOR JSON PATH, Root('Expenses'))
    RETURN @return
END
```

Now I call it in SSMS:

```
SELECT TRIM( dbo.get_all_json('1')) json_fm_func;
```

And I get this result back:

[image]

```
SELECT TRIM( dbo.get_all_json('1')) json_fm_func;
```

What went wrong?

Comment: Always specify a length when defining a varchar or nvarchar   ... returns nvarchar(max),  Be sure to fix @return as well

Comment: If you **don't specify** an explicit length on a `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` parameter for a function or stored procedure, it defaults to a length of **1 character** .... - works as designed (and documented)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `nvarchar` to `nvarchar(max)`

```
create function [dbo].[get_all_json] (@input nvarchar(max)) 
--the argument (@input) is never used. you can create your function without argument. 
returns nvarchar(max) as
begin
    declare @return nvarchar(max)
    set  @return =  (SELECT Id as [Expense.Id]
      ,Amount As [Expense.Amount]
      ,StudentName As [Expense.StudentName]
          FROM [dbo].[Expenses] FOR JSON PATH, Root('Expenses'))
    return @return
end
```

Comment: Hi 5 @Behnam! Have a great evening